# Multiple Sink for Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: copy, azure-data-factory

In Azure Data Factory pipeline, Can I have a copy activity with two SINKs? I have one source and 2 sinks (One Azure Data lake store for downstream processing and the other for archival on Blob Storage).

Answer (score 9):

That’s definitively possible. Just add a second activity in the same pipeline with the same Input dataset but a different output dataset.

The JSON will then look something like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://datafactories.schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-09-01/Microsoft.DataFactory.Pipeline.json",
    "name": "CopyActivity1",
    "properties": {
        "description": "Copy data from blob to a sql server table",
      "activities": [
        {
          "name": "CopyActivityTemplate",
          "type": "Copy",
          "inputs": [
            {
              "name": "AzureBlobLocation1"
            }
          ],
          "outputs": [
            {
              "name": "AzureSqlTableLocation1"
            }
          ],
          "typeProperties": {
            "source": {
              "type": "BlobSource"
          },
        },
        {
          "name": "CopyActivityTemplate2",
          "type": "Copy",
          "inputs": [
            {
              "name": "AzureBlobLocation1"
            }
          ],
          "outputs": [
            {
              "name": "AzureSqlTableLocation2"
            }
          ],
          "typeProperties": {
            "source": {
              "type": "BlobSource"
            },          
          },
        }
      ],
        "start": "2016-12-05T22:00:00Z",
        "end": "2016-12-06T01:00:00Z"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Michael. Appreciate your help here. This did help me move to next steps in my data ingestion process. Thank you again! :)

Comment: glad to help :-) Can you mark it as an answer? thanks.

Comment: @AjayDevulapalli In this scenario are you using the same table/query in the source data set?

Answer (score 2):

So basically you need to add another activity with same source.